# Failing to mount exFat on Linux

Tags: linux, mount, exfat

I have an exFAT filesystem in a microSD card (devide `/dev/sdi` appears in `dmesg` when I plug it using a microSD to USB adapter). The card works on Android, and I want to mount it in Fedora 23. I tried these:

```
 mount /dev/sdi1 /mnt/gn-sd
 mount -t exfat /dev/sdi1 /mnt/gn-sd
 mount.exfat /dev/sdi1 /mnt/gn-sd
 mount -a -t exfat /dev/sdi1 /mnt/gn-sd
```

All of them give the very same output:

```
 FUSE exfat 1.2.3
```

Yet, the device is not mounted anywhere. Nothing happened, `mount` command shows nothing. The command `fsck /dev/sdi1` simply gives

```
 fsck from util-linux 2.28
```

and exits immediately with exit code 0. The command `sfdisk -l /dev/sdi` gives the following:

```
Disk /dev/sdi: 59.5 GiB, 63864569856 bytes, 124735488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdi1  *     2048 124735487 124733440 59.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

and this is `dmesg` output:

```
usb 3-11: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-11: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0736
usb 3-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
usb 3-11: Product: USB Storage
usb 3-11: Manufacturer: Generic
usb 3-11: SerialNumber: 000000000272
usb-storage 3-11:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi host12: usb-storage 3-11:1.0
scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   0272 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg9 type 0
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] 124735488 512-byte logical blocks: (63.9 GB/59.5 GiB)
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] Write Protect is off
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] Mode Sense: 0b 00 00 08
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] No Caching mode page found
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] Assuming drive cache: write through
 sdi: sdi1
sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] Attached SCSI removable disk
 sdi: sdi1
```

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Id `c` in `fdisk` output indicates *FAT32*, *exFAT* would be `7`; yet it may or may not correspond with actual filesystem. You can invoke `sudo file -s /dev/sdi1` to check the filesystem out.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, `file` command just says "DOS/MBR boot sector". No indication of filesystem. Yet, Android shows files inside the card that I can change, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have *exfat* support? It does not come by default with most (all?) distros in Linux. First you should install these two packages,

```
sudo apt-get install -y exfat-utils exfat-fuse
```

and then you should try to mount your device.

Comment: I tried that also. Trying to mount it as vfat gives "wrong fs type..." I tried exfat because of the FUSE output. This is a card formated in an Android phone.

Comment: the `mount` man page doesn't list all possible filesystems. For example it doesn't list F2FS which is an extremely common FS for Linux nowadays

Comment: after installing the above; `$ udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sdi1` ?